# Invalid hook call along with TypeError when reading useState with web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm currently trying to work with React Native, and have managed to use [Expo](https://expo.dev/client?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=CjwKCAjwpJWoBhA8EiwAHZFzfjcZvisGcK0qMgTx_cus-YC84cfb-WUHS5YY6UncXMsu9er-6PnT1RoC-asQAvD_BwE) to sucessfully launch a blank project with a managed workflow. I have successfully managed to create an Android virtual device and have my app run with no issues where. However, when starting the app on a browser (pressing "W" within the console with Expo Go), I see a blank screen and several errors within Chrome's console. I am entirely new to react, and have some minor JavaScript, HTML and CSS experience. I have left the error logs and a few code snippets below.

App.js:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  //console.log('The application is now running!');
  //console.log('I am trying to type out some stuff and see how it goes');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app! Hello there</Text>
      <Text>I'm trying to type stuff out and see how well it'll work out</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#17bf44',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "TestProject",
    "slug": "TestProject",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#17bf44"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#17bf44"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to follow the instructions provided by React given within the error log, but I do not believe fixes 1 and 3 apply to me. I have checked my versions of react and react-dom, and they seem to match. [Here is the error log returned from the Google console when running my app on the web.](https://pastebin.com/2AL7pDQv)

Is there any more information I can provide? Any suggestions as to what I can try from here?

Comment: Have you written or modified any other components? The error is referring to a potentially erroneous useState call

Comment: I have not made any edits to any part of the generated code except to background colours and strings within <Text> tags. I have not made use of the useState function anywhere myself, hence my confusion.